# mySQL "Rank in Highscore"-Query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there coders around the world,

I'm working on a project where users can do certain things and gain points for it. To simplify this question let's say we got 2 tables **user** and **points**.

```
-- table user       -- table points
+---------------+    +-----------------------------+
|  id  |  name  |    |  id  |  points  |  user_id  |
+---------------+    +-----------------------------+
|  1     Tim    |    |  1      5          1        |
|  2     Tom    |    |  2      10         1        |
|  3     Marc   |    |  3      5          1        |
|  4     Tina   |    |  4      12         2        |
|  5     Lutz   |    |  5      2          2        |
+---------------+    |  6      7          1        |
                     |  7      40         3        |
                     |  8      100        1        |
                     +-----------------------------+
```

Now to get the complete highscore-list I use the following query

```
SELECT u.*, SUM( p.points ) AS sum_points
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN points p ON p.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY sum_points DESC
```

resulting in a fine highscore-list with all users from first to last

```
+------------------------------+
|  id  |  name  |  sum_points  |
+------------------------------+
|  1     Tim       127         |
|  3     Marc      40          |
|  2     Tom       14          |
|  4     Tina      0           |
|  5     Lutz      0           |
+------------------------------+
```

Alright back to the question itself. On the profile of a single user I'd like to show his ranking within the highscore-list.

Can this be done using a single query just showing that for example **Tom (id=2)** is ranked in place 3?

Thanks alot :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to ask, "how many players rank above @this_user":

```
select count(*) + 1 from 
(
    /* list of all users */
    SELECT SUM( p.points ) AS sum_points
    FROM user u
    LEFT JOIN points p ON p.user_id = u.id
    GROUP BY u.id        
) x
/* just count the ones with higher sum_points */
where sum_points > (select sum(points) from points where user_id = @this_user)
```

**Edited** to make result 1-based instead of 0-based

Comment: +1, this is what I was going for, but you got it first. One thing to note - to get the place of the user it would be count(*) + 1 (as you said this will only get the number of users with scores higher than @this_user).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  q.*,
        @r := @r + 1 AS rank
FROM    (
        SELECT  @r := 0
        ) vars,
        (
        SELECT  u.*,
                SUM(p.points) AS sum_points
        FROM
                user u
        LEFT JOIN
                points p
        ON      p.user_id = u.id
        GROUP BY
                u.id
        ORDER BY
                sum_points DESC
        ) q
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I asked for but also really helpful :)

Comment: `@Tim`: oh, sorry, got it now :)