# MySQL highscore query

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mySQL “Rank in Highscore”-Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118511/mysql-rank-in-highscore-query)

I was just wondering if there is any effective way to gather the current rank of some id based on points.

My only idea was to grab whole points and then check every record if its more or less. Something like this.

```
Select * from whatever table

$x=0
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
     if ($user == $row['user']) {
          echo "$user is rank $x out of " . count($result);
          break;
     } 

     else {
       $x++
     }
}
```

Comment: What does your db table look like?

Comment: provide some data in table format as input and output...

Comment: also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878354/ranking-joint-positions-in-mysql). Hope this helps you!!!

Comment: Thanks guys, Just sovled it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable, as shown [here](http://www.fromdual.com/ranking-mysql-results):

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT user.*, @rank:=@rank+1 AS 'rank'
FROM user
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like the "MAX" in mysql?

"SELECT max(score) as record FROM users";

This will retrieve a column with the highest score from the users table.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done in mysql:

```
SELECT  ui2.*, 
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    users ui
        WHERE  (ui.points, ui.id) >= (ui2.points, ui2.id)
        ) AS rank
FROM    users ui2
WHERE   id = @id
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use max() along with the group by clause to group the results based on certain criteria.

"SELECT max(score) as record FROM users_points group by user_id, game_id";

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users
(
id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
score int unsigned not null default 0
)
engine=innodb;

insert into users (score) values (10),(30),(50),(30),(20),(45),(20);

select 
 @r:=@r+1 as rank,
 u.id,
 u.score
from 
 users u 
inner join (select @r:=0) as r 
order by 
 u.score desc;
```